# Classloader Resource - Null value

Tags: java, maven, ant

I am using below code to print/access the root resource location in test cases:
    `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".")`

However, this yields different results when I run the test cases using Maven or ANT. For Maven build, I get the correct path "C:\....", but ANT returns `null` here.

Any idea what am I missing here?

UPDATE: Project structure - src/resources | tst/resources.

Comment: Posting your project folder structure and build file would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug in ANT versions prior to 2.5, which lead ANT to neither copy tst/resources nor add them to the class-path ([JIRA#IO-451](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-451)).

Answer (score 0):

Maven and Ant uses different class loader systems. [Maven uses the Classworlds](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-classloading.html) framework

> Maven uses the Classworlds classloading framework with which we create
>   our classloader graph.

Whereas [Ant uses the "Java's delegation model"](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#delegating-classloader)

> Ant's class loader implementation uses Java's delegation model

Your result may then differ because the `ClassLoader` on which your are calling `getResource(".")` is not the same between Maven and Ant. The results you will yield is highly dependent on the `ClassLoader` implementation.

Comment: I expect that, but shouldn't it print some value, albeit a different one but not null?